# Como definir uma cláusula where dinamica no mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, relacionamento, where

Tenho 2 tabelas "pessoas" e "empresas", na tabela de pessoas existe o campo "endereco_correspondencia", que pode receber "empresarial" ou "residencial".
Preciso de uma busca onde defino UFs, por exemplo ["SP", "RJ"] e me retorne as "pessoas" onde a UF é a mesma definida em "endereco_correspondencia".

Segue o código que tentei sem sucesso, mas pode ajudar a resumir a pergunta:

```
SELECT nome  FROM pessoas
LEFT JOIN empresas ON empreas.id = pessoas.empresa_id
CASE pessoas.endereco_correspondencia  = 'residencial' 
THEN WHERE pessoas.uf IN('SP','RJ')
ELSE WHERE empresas.uf IN('SP','RJ');
```

Isso realmente é possivel de se fazer? se sim, sobre oque preciso estudar?

```html
<!--[if IE]><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=5,IE=9" ><![endif]-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Diagrama sem nome.drawio.html</title>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
</head>
<body>
<div class="mxgraph" style="max-width:100%;border:1px solid transparent;" data-mxgraph="{&quot;highlight&quot;:&quot;#0000ff&quot;,&quot;nav&quot;:true,&quot;resize&quot;:true,&quot;xml&quot;:&quot;&lt;mxfile host=\&quot;app.diagrams.net\&quot; modified=\&quot;2022-08-30T14:20:49.303Z\&quot; agent=\&quot;5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.0.0 Safari/537.36\&quot; etag=\&quot;ya4NmdY-ZdcqZ8pL7N_F\&quot; version=\&quot;20.2.7\&quot; type=\&quot;device\&quot;&gt;&lt;diagram id=\&quot;YhfaojcMS7rL5nVXc_Fy\&quot; name=\&quot;Página-1\&quot;&gt;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&lt;/diagram&gt;&lt;/mxfile&gt;&quot;,&quot;toolbar&quot;:&quot;pages zoom layers lightbox&quot;,&quot;page&quot;:0}"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://app.diagrams.net/js/viewer-static.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Não está claro o que você quer de dinâmico como diz no título da pergunta. E não pode usar vários WHEREs, para múltiplas condições use AND e/ou OR numa única cláusula WHERE.

Comment: Com o dinâmico, me referi que á condição e feita em tempo de execução, como em um looping, que imagino que deve se comportart parecido em uma instrução SQL, mas realmente 'dinâmico', não foi a melhor abordagem pra definição dessa pergunta.

Comment: where ( (pessoas.endereco_correspondencia = 'residencial' and 
         pessoas.uf IN('SP','RJ') 
         or
        (pessoas.endereco_correspondencia <> 'residencial' and 
         empresas.uf IN('SP','RJ') )

Answer (score -2):

você usa o case no where desta forma: tenta assim -->

```
SELECT nome FROM pessoas
LEFT JOIN empresas ON empreas.id = pessoas.empresa_id
1=1
AND CASE
          WHEN pessoas.endereco_correspondencia  = 'residencial' THEN pessoas.uf IN('SP','RJ')
          empresas.uf IN('SP','RJ')
      END;
```

você pode ler mais em: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-case-function/